# Free homotopy of loops

Tags: differential-geometry, string-theory, chern-simons-theory

Given a topological space $X$, a loop based at $x_{0}$ is defined to be a continuous function

$$\gamma \colon [0,1]\to X$$

such that the starting point $γ(0) $ and the end point $γ(1) $ are both equal to  $ x_{0}. $

A free homotopy of loops is a continuous map $H:[0,1]×[0,1]→X$ such that $γ_s(t):=H(s,t)$ is a loop for each fixed $s∈[0,1]$, that is $H(s,0)=H(s,1)$ for all $s∈[0,1]$.

Can I construct a cohomology $H(s,0)\rightarrow H(s,t)\rightarrow H(s,t_2)\rightarrow H(s,t_3)$ thus making a time-ordered series and a thus define an evolution operator? Continuity of $H$ as a map of two variables is what gives us a continuous family of continuous loops.

If I also add to my definition that $H^{-1}$ exists. Is it true that the union of all $y$s is given by the wedge product $w=ds\wedge dt$? Thus Stokes theorem

$$\int_{\partial M} \omega = \int_M d\omega$$

shows it has the form of a Chern-Simons theory or am I wrong?

$S_1\times S_1$ will be a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ thus the boundary will be $\mathbb{R}^{2n-1}$, via integration we should get the Lagrangian for 2-dimensional Chern Simons theory thus the action would be equivalent to the Nambu-Goto action.

Comment: "thus the action would be equivalent to the Nambu-Goto action." It will not; your construction is purely topological, and the NG action involves a metric.

Comment: Sorry its more accurate to say it will be correlated. But chern simeon is a type of topological string theory.

Comment: It's the other way around.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Voting to close since this seems like a purely math question.